# Scrollbar in the middle of the div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with `overflow-y: scroll;`
In this div, I display a table with 3 columns and many rows. For desing purpose, I'd like to know if it's possible to have the scroll bar in the middle of the div (vertically in the middle)

I'd like to have 2 columns, the scroll bar, and then the 3rd column.
Is that possible ?

Thanks

Comment: nope, it's not possible. Scrollbars are browser default elements in which you have poor control over. In all major browsers (and some minor) you can change shape and color but that's all.

Comment: That's sad. I did change the color already. Thanks anyway

Comment: You're welcome, please, close question when you can and upvote for further people arriving here.